# make auto click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using trigger click for auto click wit trimmer on an item can anyone help me to put this in infinity loop so it keep repeat it self again and again but using jQuery not JavaScript.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#click2').trigger('click');
}, 4e3);

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#click2').trigger('click');
}, 8e3);

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#click3').trigger('click');
}, 12e3);
```

Comment: use `setInterval` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: jQuery is written in and runs on JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(function() {
      $('#click2').trigger('click');
      setTimeout(function() {
           $('#click3').trigger('click');
      }, 500)
}, 1000 /* in milliseconds */);
```

This triggers both button clicks every second.

Not sure why you need this though. I am sure there is a better way to achieve what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: i'm trying to make some experiment to improve my skills but  here is the thing it will create a loop to click each one but it will click each one in a very fast way

Comment: With the second argument (the 1000 in my example) you can specify the interval in milliseconds. So my example runs every 1000 milliseconds, i.e. every second.

Comment: thx for the explanation but i think you didn't understand my question it will click all of them every 1000 millisecond right ? so it will will click all of them so fast so i want to put a timer for each click for example click the first after 5 second click the second after 5 second

Comment: OK, I think I got it. Check the updated answer.  Basically I put a `setTimeout` inside the `setInterval`. Or maybe you meant you just want two different timers. In this case just use two `setInterval` each handling one click-trigger.

Comment: thank you very much it worked and it click every 500 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

use `setInterval`

```
setInterval(function() {
   $('#click2').trigger('click');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: may i ask what  about 8e3 which is the time for each time to click

Comment: `8e3` = `8000` so 8 seconds.

Comment: 8e3 is 8000 milliseconds or 1 click every 8 seconds